# Strange Error: internal-temp-output-buffer-show

Tags: emacs, elisp

Suddenly I have started getting the following strange message when doing `describe-function`:

```
ad-Orig-describe-function: Symbol's function definition is void: internal-temp-output-buffer-show
```

I can't get any sense of related Google hits.

Ideas anyone?

Comment: The error message implicates advice.  You probably have a `defadvice` on `describe-function` or a function invoked from it.  I'd start by enabling `debug-on-error` and examining the backtrace (since you apparently cannot run `describe-function` on itself to see whether it has advice defined for it ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You give little information on what Emacs version you're using, if you've updated it recently, etc. Seems that this call is somewhat fixed in some compiled files but you're using an Emacs previous to version 24, which is the first that includes this function.

My advice would be to reinstall Emacs (and associated packages you installed aside such as `org-mode`, etc.), or start Emacs without the site-configuration (options `-q` and `--no-site-file`), and be adding them one by one. Also, be sure you're using Emacs 24 (with `emacs --version`).